# Replace multiple occurrence of a character in a string in php

Tags: php, string, replace

```
$string = IT_Support_/_Help_Desk // what I have
$whatIwant = IT Support Help Desk // what I want
```

I have this string and I want to replace all accurrence of the space "_" to " "

Comment: Please note: I have tried str_replace but it only works for two word strings like "hello_world" but not "hey_there_hello_world", which is quite weird because it word when I first modified the string with "_" underscores to pass them to an html element via data attribute but now replacing them again on back-end again with " " (spaces) only works for two word strings. Any help with regex using preg_match??

Comment: What about `str_replace(['_', '/', '  '], ' ', $str)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for this with a combination of non word characters `\W` and `_` like below:

```
<?php

$string = "IT_Support_/_Help_Desk";

echo preg_replace('/[_\W]+/', ' ', $string);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ended up using javascript .replaceAll method. This works too

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "IT_Support_/_Help_Desk";
$string = preg_replace('~[\\\\\/:*?"<>|_]~', ' ', $string);

echo $string;
```